# How do I do the border-bottom trick for tabbed navigation BUT with box-shadow not border?

Tags: css, tabs, navigation, nav

See here for code: http://jsfiddle.net/9pezn/

I know how to do the position bottom, negative margin trick with a bottom-border to make a hovered/active "tab" z-index over it but have been unable to recreate this effect when using a box-shadow. Any ideas?

I.E. I want the main navigation tabs to be on top of the box-shadow! I am essentially attempting to replicate what the Nike.com navigation does. E.g. When you hover over "Sports," then the bottom shadow is covered.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I would avoid using :before and :after if you have, and put the shadows on the #primary ul li then you can take them away with #primary ul li:hover.

Comment: If I only have the shadows on the LI's then the shadow of the main navigation doesn't go across the entire page

Comment: add a shadow class to whatever is left and right of the lis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I'm willing to settle for: http://jsfiddle.net/LVppY/

Scott, you were on the right track that it could be done with z-index

Answer (score 0):

<s>`z-index` is your friend.</s>

Set the first-level navigation to `z-index:1` and then set the second-level navigation to `z-index:2` and it should sit on top of the `box-shadow` from the first-level navigation.

Long story short, Nike did it with a series of cleverly stacked images. I'm not positive you can do this with a native box-shadow implimentation, for two reasons:

1) the box-shadow is tied to the z-index of the element, meaning you can't pull the children of nav1 above the children of nav2 without causing the nav1 box-shadow to overlap nav2.

2) If you found a way to get around it (perhaps by applying individual box-shadows to each nav "tab" instead of the container as a whole, then the shadows would slightly overlap, causing darker spots.

It's possible there's a solution out there that I'm missing, but this is one of those cases where I would probably throw in the towel and use images instead.

Comment: This would overlap the ENTIRE drop shadow...  I only want to cover up the shadow underneath the ACTIVE li

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. Editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Scott!  I found a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LVppY/